# Maclaurin Series - finding the co-efficients for functions that require the product rule

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have just been introduced to the Maclaurin series, and one of the questions I have requires that I find the Maclaurin series for the function $$ f(x) = 3x^2\sin(2x)$$

The way I considered approaching the problem was to find the $f^n$th derivative at 0, and then use $$C_n = \frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$$ to find the co-efficients needed to write down the terms of the series.

However, taking derivatives of the given function to the seventh derivative for example, becomes large and tedious because I would need to invoke the product rule at each step. Is there any simpler way to find the Maclaurin series for such functions that is accessible at my level, or do I simply have to use the brute force method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$. Then replace all of the $x$'s with $2x$'s. After that, multiply the whole series through by $3x^{2}$. Then you will have your desired series.

Comment: I edited it, thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks, that makes sense.